# How to set file upload limit in several files conditions

Tags: html, function

I'm having a trouble in one of my function for my files upload.Currently I've set a condition in my files upload for image where user can't upload more than 500KB for images(jpg..png..etc).Here my code for the function of it.

```js
function fileValidation(){
   var UploadFieldID = "vasplus_multiple_files";
   var MaxSizeInBytes = 500000;
   var fld = document.getElementById(UploadFieldID);
   var filePath = fld.value;
   var allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.tiff|\.tif|\.bump)$/i;
   if( fld.files && fld.files.length == 1 && fld.files[0].size > MaxSizeInBytes && allowedExtensions.exec(filePath))
   {
      alert("The file size for images must be no more than " + parseInt(MaxSizeInBytes/1000) + "KB. Please remove the file.");
      fld.value='';
      return false;
   } else {
     console.log("upload valid");
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="vasplus_multiple_files" onchange="fileValidation()">
```

But right now I did like to add another condition for the files upload for document types files like (doc..pdf..etc).The condition I would like to set for the doc part is :

1. If user choose to upload `a file`(doc types) it must not more than `10 MB.`
2. If user choose to upload `multiple`(doc types) files the max total for it is `50MB.`

Did anyone know the solution for this problem?Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do not check only by file extension in client side; instead do file extension check, mime type check, and file validity in server side. A smart malicious user can upload a file with any extension and even make custom HTTP request outside the browser (ex: with ```curl```). A simple malicious user can always just disable his/her browser's javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the info..will fix on tht later on.. but currently I'm just stuck in setting the new condition in the function.